# How to remove margin in between <li> in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm starting to learn HTML and CSS and was wondering if there is a way to remove or reduce the `margin` in between those two list items?

See snippet & picture below:

```css
#main {
  color: black;
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ13lX20FqU" target="_blank">basic html with basic tags</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h5><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_li.asp" target="_blank">basic tags colleciton</a></h5>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Well did you try setting a value for the `margin`?

Comment: You can use developer tools integrated in browser to check which space on the page belongs to which element. That way you could see that your free space is a margin of h-tags.

Comment: @Turnip tried using i tried using li{margin: 0;} and li{padding: 0;} it just remove the space on left side,

Comment: As others have said, the issue is caused by the default margins around the heading tags, i.e. h4 and h5.  However, I don't think it's best practice to use heading tags within lists, and you would be better off removing the heading tags from the list and just styling the list li tags instead.

Comment: @Turnip ow you saying i should costumize the sizes on css, instead of using headings?

Comment: Not necessarily. I was eluding to the fact that you hadn't shown us any of your attempts to fix the problem or explained why they didn't work.

Comment: @Turnip ooops sorry i deleted them. but here's my attemp li{margin: 0;} and li{padding: 0;}

Answer (score 4):

> All heading elements like `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` upto `<h6>` have some
>   default margin in all browsers(Can vary from browser to browser).

You need to remove or reset this margin as per your needs.

```
#main h4,
#main h5 {margin: 0;}
```

```css
#main{
  color: black;
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}

#main h4,
#main h5 {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ13lX20FqU" target="_blank">basic html with basic tags</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h5><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_li.asp" target="_blank">basic tags colleciton</a></h5>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>   
</div>
```

Comment: sire, this solve my problem thanks! but i want to clarfiy, why you include h4 since i only want my h5 to move upwards,

Comment: @jrdn128 If you end up only including the H5, you would still have a margin between the two as Both the H4 and the H5 has a default margin (as Muhammad said in his original post). That is why you include both. However if you like there to be a little space there, then just exclude the H4.

Comment: @ThomasFonn thanks sire! i tried and you're right, since h4 has larger margins so it still consume a lot of space between them

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the margins are from the headings, try;

```css
#main{
    color: black;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
}
h4, h5{
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
 <ol>
  <li>
  <h4><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ13lX20FqU" target="_blank">basic html with basic tags</a></h4>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <h5><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_li.asp" target="_blank">basic tags colleciton</a></h5>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ol>   
</div>
```

Comment: yes sire, i didnt know headings has default margins, but why need to include the h4? since i only want to adjust my h5 margins so it will move up wards

Comment: You don't need to include the h4 if you don't want to.  I just assumed you wanted to remove all the margins.

Comment: i tried removing only the h4's margins. but still there a lot of space between them, thanks i fully understand now

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```css
#main{
  color: black;
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
}

li h4, h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ13lX20FqU" target="_blank">basic html with basic tags</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h5><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_li.asp" target="_blank">basic tags colleciton</a></h5>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol> 
</div>
```